# fill values with next value on the same group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table, I would like to group by "A","B" then replace the null value in "C" by the max value of "C" inside the group

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | null |

I would then have this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | **0** |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | null |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yoou can do it like so:

```
select A , B , max(C) over (partition by A,B) C
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `MAX` window function.

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       MAX(C) OVER(PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY A,B) C
FROM T
```

Comment: Thank you @d-shih :))))) it's perfect !  I was complicating my existence alone ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *change* the value, use `update`:

```
update t
    set c = (select max(t2.c) from t t2 where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b)
    where c is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `subquery` to find the `max` and then `update` in actual table

```
update mytable set C=newC from mytable inner join
(select A, B, max(C) as newC from mytable group by A, B) as temp on mytable.A=temp.A and mytable.B=temp.B
where mytable.C is NULL and temp.newC is not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery to do so:

```
update tab t
    set c = (select max(c) from tab  where a = t.a and b = t.b)
    where c is null;
```